# Outlook web addins is not loading in Edge and Chrome

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I have developed an addin for outlook using node.js and it is opening in browser. But it is not giving 
[image]

I have attached here Manifest.xml. It is working for Outlook desktop 2016 but not working for browser while using same email in outlook.com via chrome and Edge or any browser

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!--Created:ce44715c-8c4e-446b-879c-ea9ebe0f09c8-->
   <OfficeApp 
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" 
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0"
```

xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.0" 
   xsi:type="MailApp">

8F12FED3-242A-483E-BDAC-3CD0089CE22B
  1.3.0.0
  Portlr
  en-US

https://outlook-addins.herokuapp.com
    https://outlook.office365.com
    https://outlook.live.com

250

ReadWriteItem
  
    
    
  
  false

```
    <DesktopFormFactor>
      <!-- Location of the Functions that UI-less buttons can trigger (ExecuteFunction Actions). -->
      <FunctionFile resid="functionFile" />

      <!-- Message Read -->
      <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="AppointmentOrganizerCommandSurface">
        <!-- Use the default tab of the ExtensionPoint or create your own with <CustomTab id="myTab"> -->
        <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
          <!-- Up to 6 Groups added per Tab -->
          <Group id="msgReadGroup">
            <Label resid="groupLabel" />
            <!-- Launch the add-in : task pane button -->
            <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
              <Label resid="paneReadButtonLabel" />
              <Supertip>
                <Title resid="paneReadSuperTipTitle" />
                <Description resid="paneReadSuperTipDescription" />
              </Supertip>
              <Icon>
                <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16" />
                <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32" />
                <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80" />
              </Icon>
              <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                <SourceLocation resid="messageReadTaskPaneUrl" />
              </Action>
            </Control>
            <!-- Go to http://aka.ms/ButtonCommands to learn how to add more Controls: ExecuteFunction and Menu -->
          </Group>
        </OfficeTab>
      </ExtensionPoint> 
       <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="AppointmentAttendeeCommandSurface">
        <!-- Use the default tab of the ExtensionPoint or create your own with <CustomTab id="myTab"> -->
        <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
          <!-- Up to 6 Groups added per Tab -->
          <Group id="msgReadGroupRead">
            <Label resid="groupLabelRead" />
            <!-- Launch the add-in : task pane button -->
            <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButtonRead">
              <Label resid="paneReadButtonLabelRead" />
              <Supertip>
                <Title resid="paneReadSuperTipTitleRead" />
                <Description resid="paneReadSuperTipDescriptionRead" />
              </Supertip>
              <Icon>
                <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16" />
                <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32" />
                <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80" />
              </Icon>
              <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                <SourceLocation resid="messageReadTaskPaneUrlRead" />
              </Action>
            </Control>
            <!-- Go to http://aka.ms/ButtonCommands to learn how to add more Controls: ExecuteFunction and Menu -->
          </Group>
        </OfficeTab>
      </ExtensionPoint>           
      <!-- Go to http://aka.ms/ExtensionPointsCommands to learn how to add more Extension Points: MessageRead, AppointmentOrganizer, AppointmentAttendee -->
    </DesktopFormFactor>
  </Host>
</Hosts>

<Resources>
  <bt:Images>
    <bt:Image id="icon16" DefaultValue="https://outlook-addins.herokuapp.com/images/icon16.png"/>
    <bt:Image id="icon32" DefaultValue="https://outlook-addins.herokuapp.com/images/icon32.png"/>
    <bt:Image id="icon80" DefaultValue="https://outlook-addins.herokuapp.com/images/icon80.png"/>
  </bt:Images>
  <bt:Urls>
    <bt:Url id="functionFile" DefaultValue="https://outlook-addins.herokuapp.com/functions/functionFile.html"/>
    <bt:Url id="messageReadTaskPaneUrl" DefaultValue="https://outlook-addins.herokuapp.com/login.html"/>
    <bt:Url id="messageReadTaskPaneUrlRead" DefaultValue="https://outlook-addins.herokuapp.com/login.html"/>
  </bt:Urls>
  <bt:ShortStrings>
    <bt:String id="groupLabel" DefaultValue="Portlr Event Logger"/>
    <bt:String id="customTabLabel"  DefaultValue="My Add-in Tab"/>
    <bt:String id="paneReadButtonLabel" DefaultValue="Portlr"/>
    <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipTitle" DefaultValue="Portlr"/>
    <bt:String id="groupLabelRead" DefaultValue="Portlr Event Logger"/>        
    <bt:String id="paneReadButtonLabelRead" DefaultValue="Portlr"/>
    <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipTitleRead" DefaultValue="Portlr"/>
  </bt:ShortStrings>
  <bt:LongStrings>
    <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipDescription" DefaultValue="Portlr reads appointment data"/>
    <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipDescriptionRead" DefaultValue="Portlr reads appointment data"/>
  </bt:LongStrings>
</Resources>
```

Comment: Something odd happened when you pasted in the manifest, only part of it showed like code.  Look at a Fiddler / browser network trace to see if there are any errors there, and look at the browser's console log to see if there are console JS errors.

Comment: I have not getting any issue in browser . I test in Edge and not working becuse edge give more meanigfull error than chrome

Comment: Check the Javascript console for any browser that experience the issue.  Did you see any network issues?  Please edit the question to include the whole manifest file.

Comment: Can you please supply us with the proper manifest? The copy pasted manifest seems broken in places.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT I changed technology using knockout.js and it is working.